# Why this code is not working properly in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I need some help because I have a code that I suppose it has to run good but is not working and I don't know why. I want to get the clients charges and insert into my database. Basically I have two problems, first is I got 4 charges from stripe but the code is inserting only 3 into the database even when I'm seen all are coming from stripe.
The second problem is intentionally I'm not doing commit and I'm seen the charges inserted into the database. How that is possible, the transaction is not finished yet. I really appreciate any help.

```
exports.getPaymentsFromStripe = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        pool.query('BEGIN').then((res) => {
            return pool.query(' SELECT id, stripe_customer_id FROM client WHERE client.active = true AND stripe_customer_id IS NOT NULL ');
        })
            .then((client) => {
                if (client.rows.length > 0) {
                    pool.query(' TRUNCATE TABLE payment_subscription')
                    return client;
                }
            })
            .then((client) => {
                pool.query(' ALTER SEQUENCE public.payment_subscription_id_seq RESTART 1;  ALTER SEQUENCE public.payment_subscription_id_seq  START WITH 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE;')
                return client;
            })
            .then((client) => {
                const charges = stripe.charges.list({
                    customer: client.rows[0].stripe_customer_id
                })
                .then((charges) => {
                    charges.data.forEach(c => {
                        const result = pool.query(' INSERT INTO payment_subscription (card_number, date, transaction_id, brand, amount, id_masseur) ' +
                            ' VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)', ['****' + c.payment_method_details.card.last4, c.created, c.balance_transaction, c.payment_method_details.card.brand, c.amount, client.rows[0].id]);
                    })

                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('finish the transaction')
                })
            })
            


    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: All your `pool.query()` function calls are asynchronous, but you're not using `await` or `.then()` or returning them into the promise chain (for some of them) so they just run independently and things are not properly sequenced.  You also have `.then()` handlers that don't return anything, except you expect chained `.then()` handlers to get values that won't be there.

Comment: Which exact NPM module are you using for your database?

Comment: If you're actually using a version of your database that supports promises, then this would be a ton simpler to code using `await` where you `await` every database call and get rid of all `.then()` handlers, but I think it has to be seriously redesigned to avoid race conditions - as just fixing the sequencing of these steps won't be the right solution.  It will appear to work, but will be subject to problems in production under load.

Comment: This code also is missing a lot of error handling.  There are no `.catch()` statements to handle any promise rejections.  And, the code attempts to send an error status, but doesn't send any success status so it's unsymmetrical in that regard.  It also doesn't accurately communicate back completion or error to the caller for the caller to send a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from complete, but this shows you how to properly sequence your database operations using `await`.  This assumes you're using a database driver that supports promises.

```
exports.getPaymentsFromStripe = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await pool.query('BEGIN');
        const client = await pool.query(' SELECT id, stripe_customer_id FROM client WHERE client.active = true AND stripe_customer_id IS NOT NULL ');
        if (client.rows.length > 0) {
            await pool.query(' TRUNCATE TABLE payment_subscription');
        }
        await pool.query(' ALTER SEQUENCE public.payment_subscription_id_seq RESTART 1;  ALTER SEQUENCE public.payment_subscription_id_seq  START WITH 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE;');
        const charges = stripe.charges.list({
            customer: client.rows[0].stripe_customer_id
        });
        for (let c of charges) {
            await pool.query(' INSERT INTO payment_subscription (card_number, date, transaction_id, brand, amount, id_masseur) ' +
                ' VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)', ['****' + c.payment_method_details.card.last4, c.created, c.balance_transaction, c.payment_method_details.card.brand, c.amount, client.rows[0].id]);
        }
        console.log('finish the transaction');
        // probably need to finish the transaction here
        res.send("finished");
    } catch (error) {
        // probably need to rollback the transaction here
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

To address other issues here, you will probably need some sql-specific help to get the transaction parts right and make sure you aren't subject to any race conditions if more than one client is trying to do something similar at the same time.

This code addresses the sequencing of your database operations only and adds rudimentary error handling.

Comment: Thank you very much jfriend00, Thanks for give me your help. I'm pretty new programming in nodejs, the code wasn't finished because when I saw the problem I ask for help. But now I can improve the code based on your recommendations. By the way I'm using express. Best regards.